# sending bulk emails in background

Tags: java, google-app-engine, email

I have a few thousand registered users and i want to send all of them an email update about new features.

What i have tried: Manually triggering a request which invokes a [task](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/) in the background which would go through all the users & send to anyone it hadn't sent. Now, Im hitting timeout for it (10 min).

Any ideas how i can scale this?

Answer (score 1):

make a deferred task (so it returns immediately) that takes only the first N email addresses and sends email, then have it create another task before it exists that does the same thing. The last task will have no more emails to send and can just exit.

There are also various queues you can use for this sort of thing, or create a backend that persists and can run long running tasks.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred

Comment: I thought about it. It makes things uglier i thought. I will rethink about how i can do that more cleanly.

Comment: I had a look at https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/backends/ (Backend instances - which have no timeouts). Will need to look at pricing.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a backend and use it as a target for your task. Backends do not have a time limit.

Just remember to mark users you already processed. When a task fails (for any reason), it retries itself - you want to skip users you already processed during the previous attempt.

Comment: I had a look at developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/backends (Backend instances - which have no timeouts). Will need to look at pricing.